# How to concatenate Apache Arrow files with identical structure in julia

Tags: dataframe, julia, apache-arrow

How can I concatenate several Arrow files with identical structure into a single Arrow file without reading each file into memory? I am using Arrow.jl and the Arrow files represent dataframes with identical structure and the combined dataframes are larger than available memory. I have been doing the following:

```julia
function openhhmembershipchunk(basedirectory::String, node::String, chunk::Int64)
    open(joinpath(basedirectory, node, "DayExtraction", "HouseholdMembershipDays$(chunk).arrow")) do io
        return Arrow.Table(io) |> DataFrame
    end;
end
"Concatenate household membership day batches"
function combinehhmembershipdaybatch(basedirectory::String, node::String, batches)
    d = openhhmembershipchunk(basedirectory::String, node::String, 1)
    days = copy(d)
    for i = 2:batches
        m = openhhmembershipchunk(basedirectory::String, node::String, i)
        append!(days, m)
    end
    Arrow.write(joinpath(basedirectory, node, "DayExtraction", "HouseholdMembershipDays.arrow"), days, compress=:zstd)
    #delete chunks
    for i = 1:batches
        rm(joinpath(basedirectory, node, "DayExtraction", "HouseholdMembershipDays$(i).arrow"))
    end
    return nothing
end #combinehhresidencydaybatch
```

Comment: At the very least, you don't need to convert to and from `DataFrame`

Comment: Yes, but how do I append Arrow tables, can I just use append!?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it is helpful to anyone.  This can now be done with Arrow.append() in two ways.

1. Create an initial file with `Arrow.write("filepath", file = false)`   keyword file has to be set to false as noted [here](https://arrow.juliadata.org/stable/reference/#Arrow.append).  Append to it with `Arrow.append(filepath,NewDataFrame)`
2. You can also create the file and append to it directly with something like

```
for d = GroupDataFrame
Arrow.append("newfilepath", d)
end
```

As noted by bkamins [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/arrow-stream-usage-clarification/89508/5).

This should work as long as the schema of the `DataFrame` being appended is the same as that being read.